# Why is there a multi-second delay in this d3 code running?

Tags: d3.js, initialization, mouseover, freeze

I add a group of  `<span>` elements to a `<div>` and want a popup when I mouseover them.

My code works but there is a 5 (or more) second delay between the DOM being complete and the mouse events being handled.  (d3 v3 on Chrome):

```js
var popup=d3.select("body")
   .append("div")
   .attr("class","popup")
   .style("opacity",0)
   .style("overflow","auto");

var bucket=d3.select("body")
  .append("div").text("DIV")
  .attr("id","bucket");
            bucket.append("div").attr("class","xxx").text("List: ");
            document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", 
   function(e) {
     var ptypes =["Pigs","Geese","Ducks","Elephants"];
     var content=[];
     for(i=0; i<ptypes.length; i++) {
       content.push({"key":ptypes[i],"data":"xxx"});
     }
     
     keys=d3.select("body").selectAll(".xxx");
     d3.select("body").select(".xxx")
       .selectAll("p")
       .data(content)
       .enter()
       .append("span")
       .html(function(d) {return "   "+d.key+"   "; })
       .on("mouseover",function(d) {
           popup.text(d.data)
            .style("opacity",0.9)
            .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")    
            .style("top", (d3.event.pageY+20) + "px");
        })
       .on("mouseout",function(d) {
           popup.style("opacity",0)
       });
});
```

```css
div.popup {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: left;
    width: 200px; height: 200px; padding: 3px;
    background: lightsteelblue;
    border: 0px; border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<style>
div.popup {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: left;
    width: 200px; height: 200px; padding: 3px;
    background: lightsteelblue;
    border: 0px; border-radius: 4px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
            var popup=d3.select("body")
                    .append("div")
                    .attr("class","popup")
                    .style("opacity",0)
                    .style("overflow","auto");
            var bucket=d3.select("body")
                    .append("div").text("DIV")
                    .attr("id","bucket");
            bucket.append("div").attr("class","xxx").text("List: ");
            document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", 
            function(e) {
                    var ptypes =["Pigs","Geese","Ducks","Elephants"];
                    var content=[];
                    for(i=0; i<ptypes.length; i++) {

content.push({"key":ptypes[i],"data":"xxx"});
                    }
                    keys=d3.select("body").selectAll(".xxx");
                    d3.select("body").select(".xxx")
                            .selectAll("p")
                            .data(content)
                            .enter()
                            .append("span")
                            .html(function(d) {return "   "+d.key+"   "; })
                            .on("mouseover",function(d) {
                                    popup.text(d.data)
                                    .style("opacity",0.9)
                                    .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")    
                            .style("top", (d3.event.pageY+20) + "px");
                            })
                            .on("mouseout",function(d) {
                                    popup.style("opacity",0)
                            });
            });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The code works, but there is a big delay (5 or more seconds) before it gets going and recognises the mouse events.

Answer (score 1):

There's no timing issue, the pointer events appear to be working right away. The issue is that your div covers the elements you want to interact with:

[image]

I've set the opacity to 0.4 rather than 0, and we can see the div smothering your interactive elements. If you move the mouse over the "ts" of elephants, I get interaction right away. After the mouse over on the "ts", the div moves out of the way enabling interaction with the rest of the elements:

```js
var popup=d3.select("body")
   .append("div")
   .attr("class","popup")
   .style("opacity",0.4)
   .style("overflow","auto");

var bucket=d3.select("body")
  .append("div").text("DIV")
  .attr("id","bucket");
            bucket.append("div").attr("class","xxx").text("List: ");
            document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", 
   function(e) {
     var ptypes =["Pigs","Geese","Ducks","Elephants"];
     var content=[];
     for(i=0; i<ptypes.length; i++) {
       content.push({"key":ptypes[i],"data":"xxx"});
     }
     
     keys=d3.select("body").selectAll(".xxx");
     d3.select("body").select(".xxx")
       .selectAll("p")
       .data(content)
       .enter()
       .append("span")
       .html(function(d) {return "   "+d.key+"   "; })
       .on("mouseover",function(d) {
           popup.text(d.data)
            .style("opacity",0.9)
            .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")    
            .style("top", (d3.event.pageY+20) + "px");
        })
       .on("mouseout",function(d) {
           popup.style("opacity",0.4)
       });
});
```

```css
div.popup {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: left;
    width: 200px; height: 200px; padding: 3px;
    background: lightsteelblue;
    border: 0px; border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

The solution would then be to set the `pointer-events` style of the div to `none`:

```js
var popup=d3.select("body")
   .append("div")
   .attr("class","popup")
   .style("opacity",0.4)
   .style("overflow","auto");

var bucket=d3.select("body")
  .append("div").text("DIV")
  .attr("id","bucket");
            bucket.append("div").attr("class","xxx").text("List: ");
            document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", 
   function(e) {
     var ptypes =["Pigs","Geese","Ducks","Elephants"];
     var content=[];
     for(i=0; i<ptypes.length; i++) {
       content.push({"key":ptypes[i],"data":"xxx"});
     }
     
     keys=d3.select("body").selectAll(".xxx");
     d3.select("body").select(".xxx")
       .selectAll("p")
       .data(content)
       .enter()
       .append("span")
       .html(function(d) {return "   "+d.key+"   "; })
       .on("mouseover",function(d) {
           popup.text(d.data)
            .style("opacity",0.9)
            .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")    
            .style("top", (d3.event.pageY+20) + "px");
        })
       .on("mouseout",function(d) {
           popup.style("opacity",0.4)
       });
});
```

```css
div.popup {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: left;
    width: 200px; height: 200px; padding: 3px;
    background: lightsteelblue;
    border: 0px; border-radius: 4px;
    pointer-events:none;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This reminds me of the similar issue brought up in [*"How/when do event listeners get attached in d3.js?"*](/q/41768276). Not a duplicate, though.